# Python:Comparing Two Dictionaries

Tags: python

The first Dict is fixed.This Dict will remain as it is List of Countries with there Short Names.

```
firstDict={'ERITREA': 'ER', 'LAOS': 'LA', 'PORTUGAL': 'PT', "D'IVOIRE": 'CI', 'MONTENEGRO': 'ME', 'NEW CALEDONIA': 'NC', 'SVALBARD AND JAN MAYEN': 'SJ', 'BAHAMAS': 'BS', 'TOGO': 'TG', 'CROATIA': 'HR', 'LUXEMBOURG': 'LU', 'GHANA': 'GH'}
```

However This Tuple result has multiple Dict inside it.This is the format in which MySQLdb returns result:

```
result =({'count': 1L, 'country': 'Eritrea'}, {'count': 1L, 'country': 'Togo'}, {'count': 1L, 'country': 'Sierra Leone'}, {'count': 3L, 'country': 'Bahamas'}, {'count': 1L, 'country': 'Ghana'})
```

Now i want to compare these both results With COUNTRY Names and If 'Country' in Result is present in firstDict then put the value.else put the 0
The result desired is:

```
mainRes={'ER':1,'TG':1,'BS':3,'GH':0,'LU':0}
```

Comment: Your desired result is not consistent. You are asking to put '0' as well as ignore at the same time. Please check. I guess your result should be ER 1
TG 1
BS 3
GH 1

Comment: @AntonyThomas Sorry my bad. I quoted the question in wrong way.Editing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [2]: firstDict={'ERITREA': 'ER', 'LAOS': 'LA', 'PORTUGAL': 'PT', "D'IVOIRE": 'CI', 'MONTENEGRO': 'ME', 'NEW CALEDONIA': 'NC', 'SVALBARD AND JAN MAYEN': 'SJ', 'BAHAMAS': 'BS', 'TOGO': 'TG', 'CROATIA': 'HR', 'LUXEMBOURG': 'LU', 'GHANA': 'GH'}

In [3]: result =({'count': 1L, 'country': 'Eritrea'}, {'count': 1L, 'country': 'Togo'}, {'count': 1L, 'country': 'Sierra Leone'}, {'count': 3L, 'country': 'Bahamas'}, {'count': 1L, 'country': 'Ghana'})

In [4]: resdict = {r['country'].upper():r['count'] for r in result}

In [5]: mainRes = {abbrev:resdict.get(country,0) for country, abbrev in firstDict.items()}

In [6]: mainRes
Out[6]: 
{'BS': 3L,
 'CI': 0,
 'ER': 1L,
 'GH': 1L,
 'HR': 0,
 'LA': 0,
 'LU': 0,
 'ME': 0,
 'NC': 0,
 'PT': 0,
 'SJ': 0,
 'TG': 1L}
```

In Python2.6 or older, where there is no [dict comprehenions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), you could do:

```
In [13]: resdict = dict((r['country'].upper(), r['count']) for r in result)

In [14]: mainRes = dict( (abbrev, resdict.get(country,0)) for country, abbrev in firstDict.items())
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `r['country'].upper()`, given that a name like "Svalbard and Jan Mayen" won't be correctly capitalized by `.capitalize`.

Comment: @unutbu resdict = {r['country']:r['count'] for r in result}... Why this syntax is wrong in python 2.6.5

Comment: @saunjean: Dict comprehensions were introduced in Python2.7. In Python2.6 you could
use `dict` and a `generator expression`. I'll edit the post to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
mainRes = dict.fromkeys(firstDict.itervalues(), 0)

for row in result:
    countryCode = firstDict.get(row['country'].upper())
    if countryCode:
        mainRes[countryCode] = row['count']
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go thru array conversion. Just use for loops as:

```
import string
desired_result = {}
for c in result:
  country = string.upper(c['country'])
  if  country in firstDict: 
    desired_result[firstDict[country]] = c['count']
print desired_result
```